# Page displays "File not found" when I enable php-fpm chroot on debian wheezy apache2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, php-fpm, fastcgi, chroot

I set up a chroot jail for a user "bob". bob is located in /var/jails/bob

Bob has a site which is located in /var/jails/bob/bobssite.com/public_html

Everything seems to work so far, including the fact that the process is being run with bob's uid (checked with php "exec('whoami')), that is, until I set chroot in the php5-fpm config file for bob's site (/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/bobssite.com.conf):

```
    [bobssite.com]

    ; Per pool prefix
    ; It only applies on the following directives:
    ; - 'slowlog'
    ; - 'listen' (unixsocket)
    ; - 'chroot'
    ; - 'chdir'
    ; - 'php_values'
    ; - 'php_admin_values'
    ; When not set, the global prefix (or /usr) applies instead.
    ; Note: This directive can also be relative to the global prefix.
    ; Default Value: none
    ;prefix = /var/jails/bob/$pool/public_html/

    user = bob
    group = webjail
    listen = /var/run/php5-fpm_bobssite.com.sock

    listen.owner = www-data
    listen.group = www-data

    pm = dynamic
    pm.max_children = 5
    pm.start_servers = 2
    pm.min_spare_servers = 1
    pm.max_spare_servers = 3

    ; Chroot to this directory at the start. This value must be defined as an
    ; absolute path. When this value is not set, chroot is not used.
    ; Note: you can prefix with '$prefix' to chroot to the pool prefix or one
    ; of its subdirectories. If the pool prefix is not set, the global prefix
    ; will be used instead.
    ; Note: chrooting is a great security feature and should be used whenever 
    ;       possible. However, all PHP paths will be relative to the chroot
    ;       (error_log, sessions.save_path, ...).
    ; Default Value: not set

    chroot = /var/jails/bob/bobssite.com/public_html
    chdir = /
```

Now, when chroot in the above is commented out, everything works. If I set it to like /var/jails/bob/notbobssite php5-fpm doesn't restart/work because it's an invalid path. If I set it to what it's currently set at I get "File not found" when I visit the page, and this in my error.log

```
    [Thu Oct 16 10:46:39 2014] [error] [client myip] FastCGI: server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi_bobssite.com" stderr: Primary script unknown
    [Thu Oct 16 10:46:39 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client myip] Zlib: Compressed 16 to 24 : URL /php5-fcgi/user.php
```

So what's going on here? I'm guessing the debug line holds the answer, but I can't figure it out?

Here is my Apache virtual host config file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName bobssite.com
    ServerAlias www.bobssite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/jails/bob/bobssite.com/public_html/ 
    ErrorLog /var/jails/bob/bobssite.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/jails/bob/bobssite.com/access.log combined

   <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
     AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
     Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5-fcgi
     Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi_bobssite.com
     FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi_bobssite.com -socket /var/run/php5-fpm_bobssite.com.sock -pass-header Authorization
   </IfModule>

   </VirtualHost>
```